# Commit with case-change is being ignored

Tags: java, git, jenkins

As an example I have a resource folder named as;

`src/test/resources/logic/myLogic/`

When I have a commit that renames this structure to

`src/test/resources/logic/mylogic/`

This change is being ignored, and fails my Jenkins builds on *nix servers, due to the case sensitivity. Currently I do two extra commits to remedy this issue; first I delete the folder completely, commit, then insert the modified folder names, commit. This way it works, but is there no shorter route to this?

Comment: I'd probably recommend sticking to the convention in pretty much all software engineering to keep dirs lowercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way is to use below command:

`git mv --force src/test/resources/logic/myLogic/ src/test/resources/logic/mylogic/`

and then `commit` and `push`. But note that it is available only from Git 2.0.1.

In case you are on an earlier version of Git, then below sequence of commands can be used:

```
git mv src/test/resources/logic/myLogic/ src/test/resources/logic/myLogic2/
git mv src/test/resources/logic/myLogic2/ src/test/resources/logic/mylogic/
```

then `commit` and `push`.